# NavigationBar redesign when viewcontroller set tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I push segue for a particular ViewController with only a TableView, the navigationbar have strange effects, such as redesign all (GIF below).
This is how set navbar in my Custom Navigation Controller viewDidLoad method.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.accessibilityFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:     
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.frame.size.width ?? 500, height: 100)
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = .primaryColor
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance
self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
self.navigationBar.addSubview(imageView!)
imageView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
imageView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
imageView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
```

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: why you are not using titleView?

Comment: I've tried, but not showing the image...

Comment: It does if you do code properly..

Comment: of course....however i make a workaround....put a view with top constraint to safe area and height constraint=1, and attach tableview to it instead of safe area top....thank you for support @dahiya_boy